# os.Getenv("GOPATH") not retrieving value in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, go

I am noob in Golang, also I have browsed all the answers relative to this issue in stackoverflow but I haven't found anthing to answer my problem.

If I enter the command in console -> get env I got this:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/adi/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/adi/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/adi/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/adi/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/snap/go/9415"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/snap/go/9415/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.18"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build1114163046=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

but if I am trying to output

```
func main() {
    // router := gin.Default()
    // RegisterBlocklyAutomationEndpoint(router)

    fmt.Println(os.Getenv("GOPATH"))

}
```

I get an empty string. I really need to get the value in order to use it in path formation for some static resources.

Thanks!

Comment: `GOPATH` is not required to be set, and is no longer use for development. The value you're showing in `go env` is just the default. You should not be storing any static resources in GOPATH, and even if GOPATH were being used for development, the path to the source code is not relevant to the path used to deploy a service.

Comment: @Jimb ok, then if I am making a package with some static resources(html, css, js files), how to get the path programmatically?
Please give me a hint.

Comment: Like any other asset, you store them in a known location, and/or provide a configuration parameter to locate them at runtime. If you want to bundle the assets in the binary, see any of the related posts about using the "embed" package.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `go env` is not a reliable indicator of whether or not `$GOPATH` is set.

If you type `go env | grep GOPATH` and then `env | grep GOPATH`, I am willing to bet that you see something like this:

```
$ go env |grep GOPATH
GOPATH="/home/user/go"
$ env |grep GOPATH
$
```

What is happening is that `go env` is giving you the default value, but it's not actually set.

If you need to get the current working directory, then [os.Getwd()](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Getwd) is probably a better choice.

Answer (score -1):

There are better answers but consider this:

The env var GOPATH may exists buy it should be exported to be visible in a subshell